# SWT setCapture method equivalent in RAP RWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

Currently working on a RAP project.
While working on RWT, I had an already existing code written with the help of the jar `org.eclipse.swt`
and in that a class uses the method `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control#setCapture()`

But while converting this project to RAP RWT the above method is not present in the same class `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control` which RWT jar `org.eclipse.rap.rwt` pulls ins.

Does anyone know any other alernative method for the `setCapture` in RWT?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for this method in RWT: Tell us what `setCpature()` is used for. Maybe we can find a replacement or workaround.

Comment: I have a class where I want to send all my mouse events to, Right now since I don't have the `setCapture` method, i manually call the methods that are needed

Comment: You seem to have a workaround in place. If you are still interested in a `setCapture()` method in RWT, please [open an enhancement request](https://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/)